# Coherence : How to get backing map in Custom Eviction Policy implementation

Tags: java, oracle-coherence

I am implementing custom eviction policy using below reference but the problem is I need to know what is the backing cache name so that I can get CacheLoader reference. is there a way to get the `ReadWriteBackingMap` from `ConfigurableCacheMap` ?

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22837/api_customeviction.htm#COHDG168

```
public void requestEviction(int cMaximum){

    logger.debug(String.format("EvictionPolicy.requestEviction: evicting requested for cache %s", getCache()));

    ConfigurableCacheMap cache = getCache();    


    for(Iterator iter=cache.entrySet().iterator();iter.hasNext();){
        ConfigurableCacheMap.Entry entry=(ConfigurableCacheMap.Entry) iter.next();          

        // If the contents of the entry (for example the key/value) need
        // to be examined, invoke convertEntry(entry) in case
        // the entry must be deserialized
        Map.Entry convertedEntry = convertEntry(entry);
        //          

         if (entry instanceof LocalCache.Entry)
         {
             LocalCache.Entry l_entry = (LocalCache.Entry) entry;
             // Can I get the backing map here????????? 
         }
    }

}
```